# How can I name fields in an OCaml variant?

Tags: ocaml, variant

Variants with lots of fields start to get unwieldy. The role of each field ends up in comments:

```ml
type ty =
  | FunTy of (*all*) ty list * (*params*) ty list * (*return type*) ty
  ...
```

One solution is to have the value of the variant be a record.

```ml
type ty =
  | FunTy of ft
  ...
and ft = {
  forall : ty list;
  p_tys : ty list;
  ret_ty : ty
}
```

However, there's an indirection required to dereference the record fields. It doesn't matter for my purposes, but I can see this performance difference making the refactor above unidiomatic in practice.

To keep this answers objectivish, references to the OCaml docs or a style guide would help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since OCaml 4.03 (released in 2016) you can use [inline records](https://www.ocaml.org/releases/4.12/htmlman/inlinerecords.html), which give you the nice interface of the record syntax — plus, you can have mutable fields — with the same memory representation as with the tuple syntax.

```ml
type ty =
  | FunTy of {
      forall : ty list;
      p_tys : ty list;
      ret_ty : ty
    }
  ...
```

You have some facility to manipulate the contained record, but (not differently than the argument “tuple” in the tuple syntax) it is not a first-class value (see the documentation linked above for more details).

Answer (score 1):

It's a matter of style, so I will note down my opinion on this.

With this particular example, where we have a choice between specifying the Variant constructor with a tuple or with record, even I think that for too many fields, record should be used.

Pattern-Matching anyway suffices in either case, whether it's tuple or record.

Whether it's tuple or record, all fields will have to be specified when dealing with values.

However the real advantage comes from the record dealing with too many fields, as

1. Record fields are identifiable via keys, and which is more convenient to manage and fields are treated in an order-insignificant manner, which means better control at the hands of the author.
2. Tuple fields are order-significant, which means the author will have to be careful while treating tuple data

Though tuples will be lesser on the memory side, but records do have advantages when the fields grow large in number.

This opinion is strictly with respect to tuple or record. Any other combination, may follow a different opinion... from me. :-)

Comment: Asking for opinion is not allowed on SO so giving opinion only encourages it. [answer]

Comment: ...solicit opinions rather than facts. Ok, may be I need to work on my re-wording. Hmmm.. Gotta think, how to answer questions about "stylings"... Thanks @Rob, will read through that "How To Answer" link in more detail...

Comment: To Rob: although Nalin uses the word, I see nothing in this answer that would qualify as an “opinion”. These are objective facts. The original question is a problem acknowledged by the OCaml programming language community, so largely that the programming language has provided a solution for it.

Comment: The order significance becomes more significant when multiple items in the tuple have the same type. If it's `int * string * float` the type checker will catch a situation where the wrong order is used, but not in a case like `int * int * string`.

Answer (score 1):

When you see a variant type where a constructor is taking many parameter, you may wish to consider using more indirection in another way. Consider a simple, contrived example of specifying a type to build a triangle. We'd need to store coordinates for each corner in either 2D or 3D space.

```ml
type triangle = 
  Triangle_2d of float * float * (* Point A *) 
                 float * float * (* Point B *)
                 float * float   (* Point C *)
| Triangle_3d of float * float * float * (* Point A *)
                 float * float * float * (* Point B *)
                 float * float * float   (* Point C *)
```

Talk about unweildy. So let's use records.

```ml
type triangle = 
  Triangle_2d of { ax : float; ay : float; 
                   bx : float; by : float;
                   cx : float; cy : float }
| Triangle_3d of { ax : float; ay : float; az : float;
                   bx : float; by : float; bz : float;
                   cx : float; cy : float; cz : float }
```

But when we really think about it, aren't we just specifying coordinates? So maybe we should create a coordinate type.

```ml
type coordinate = 
  Coord_2d of { x : float; y : float }
| Coord_3d of { x : float; y : float; z : float }
```

And then our triangle type is simply:

```ml
type triangle = 
  Triangle_2d of { a : coord; b : coord } 
| Triangle_3d of { a : coord; b : coord; c : coord }
```

Or even:

```ml
type triangle = 
  Triangle_2d of coord * coord 
| Triangle_3d of coord * coord * coord
```

It's a lot cleaner to look at sure, but also it lets us break down the problem into smaller bites. If I want to calculate the distance between two vertices on the triangle, I don't need to do math with the whole triangle. I can simply define a function to deal with coordinates, and I can deal with the difference between 2D and 3D coordinates at this level. I could even break it down and write functions that project 3D coordinates onto a given axis or plane.